# Solr Facet and Tokenizer

Tags: solr

I have solr array field that could contain string with some separate words as a one value, for example ["Super Ball", "BlaBla", "Info"].
I need to see all those 3 values as an facet values and have case insensitive search by fields as well.

If I use next field type setting I see 3 values in facet but case insensitive search doesn't work.

```
<fieldType name="myLower" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
     <analyzer type="index"> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>    
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">     
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
   </fieldType>
```

if I use `<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>` I can use lower case search, but I see 4 facet values, becourse StandardTokenizerFactory splits "Super Ball" to 2 words.

How to manage such case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two separate fields. One for faceting and one for searching - they're different operations and different field definitions will suite each better.

Use `<copyField source="searchfield" dest="facetfield" maxChars="30000" />` to copy the contents you're sending into your searchfield to a dedicated faceting field. Use the facetfield (with either keywordtokenizer + lowercasing or just a string field if you want to keep the case intact) for faceting, and perform searches against the searchfield. The facetfield will also be used when you're applying `fq` filters when the user has picked a facet for further filtering.