# solr facet with text field, how to stop solr tokenize it into separate tokens, I want to get the whole field result

Tags: solr

1. I have a text field type named buyer, I need facet on the field. And get the whole value, nor separate tokens, how can I do? thanks a lot.
2. eg, buyer field value are "beauty inc"、"markwins llc"、"products inc", this is facet result:

```js
facet_counts: {
facet_queries: { },
facet_fields: {
buyer: [
"beauty",
4025,
"inc",
3610,
"products",
1749,
"markwins",
1604,
"llc",
913,
"cosmetics"]
}
```

it seems that solr tokenize it into separate tokens. How can I get the whole value? If I don't change text field to str field.
eg:

```js
facet_counts: {
facet_queries: { },
facet_fields: {
buyer: [
"beauty inc",
3610,
"products llc",
1749,
"markwins llc",
1604]
}
}
```

Comment: Create 2 fields for the same fields. One will have the tokenised value. Other will have the string values. For searching you can use the tokenized and for showing you can use the string one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solr Facet and Tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483832/solr-facet-and-tokenizer)

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks, if I add a copy field, I have to reindex, is that true? is there any way no reindex?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to reindex. Otherwise Solr won't be able to reprocess the text for the field (it wouldn't currently know what the input data for that exact field is, since filters can change the input value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<field name="buyer" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="buyer_facet" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

<copyField source="buyer" dest="buyer_facet"/>
```

Then you can search on "buyer" and facet on "buyer_facet" .
You need to re-index to fill the buyer_facet field.